# How to delete some specific columns in a large measurenent data which donot contain a some values?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, performance, data-analysis

i have a large measurement data which contain 35O columns after filtering(for example to A49,B0to B49,F0 toF49) with some random numbers.
**Now i want to look in to (B0 to B49) whether it has values in the range(say: between 20 and 30).If not I want to delete that columns from the measurement data.**

How to do this in python with pandas?
I want to know some faster methods for this filtering?
sample data:https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17Xjc81jkjS-64B4FGZ06SzYDRnc6J27m/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=106137353367530025738&rtpof=true&sd=true

Comment: Please provide a minimal concrete example. You could probably use `df.filter(regex='^B')` or `df.filter(like='B')`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17Xjc81jkjS-64B4FGZ06SzYDRnc6J27m/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=106137353367530025738&rtpof=true&sd=true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(In Pandas) You can apply a function on all elements of an array using the `applymap` function. You can also apply *aggregating* actions to have a single value out of a whole column. You put those two things together to have what you want.

For instance, you want to know if a given set of columns (the "B" ones) have value in some range (say, 20:30). So, you want to verify the values at the element level, but collect the column names as output.

You can do that with the following code. Execute them separately/progressively to understand what they are doing.

```py
>>> b_cols_of_interest_indx = df.filter(regex='^B').applymap(lambda x:20<x<30).any()
>>> b_cols_of_interest_indx[b_cols_of_interest_indx]
B19    True
B21    True
dtype: bool
```

Comment: I didnt'understand. Would you explain it in detail @Brandt.

Comment: @mathew Right, sorry I wrote the first version on my phone. Now you have a better version of it.

Comment: Thanks..I was able to get the column which has the value specified in the condition.**Now i want to get the columns which donot satisfy the condition(between 20 and 30) and want to delete those columns from my entire dataframe.How to do this with drop method or any other methods?**

Comment: Good @mathew. I think you need to have a look at the docs: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/getting_started/intro_tutorials/index.html . You have very basic questions, do yourself a favor and read them ;)

Comment: How to get only B19,B21 in the output of your code?

Comment: @mathew You can get the `index` attribute: `b_cols_of_interest_indx[b_cols_of_interest_indx].index`